# A single word in English for "easily make others miss the person"

Tags: word-request, word-usage

Is there a single word in English that means "easily make others miss the person"?

For example, if such word were *xqxqxq*, a sample sentence would be:

The baby *xqxqxqs* everyone because she is so cute. (if the word is a verb), or
The baby is *xqxqxqs* for everyone because she is so cute. (if the word is a verb)

Comment: `charms/is charming to | delights/is delightful to| enchants/ is enchanting to` are possibilities.

Comment: I am not sure that one person can *make* another person miss them.

Comment: CarSmack, your comment reminds me of the word "irresistible".

Comment: Was the baby trying to imprint itself on everyone's memory by being cute? Hmm... sounds like a baby thing, or a cat thing, or maybe I watched too many sequels of Twilight. :-)

Comment: @CarSmack Keep in mind that causatives are different in each language.  The OP is probably not trying to use a coercive causative despite their wording.

Comment: @snailboat, yes, I didn't try to use a coercive causative. Perhaps it would be better worded as "easily turn others into longing for the person".

Answer (score 4):

[Endear](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=endearing) may be what you are seeking and could be used as follows:

The baby *endears* herself to everyone because she is so cute

The baby is *endearing* to everyone because she is so cute

Everyone finds the baby *endearing* because she is so cute